# Scale instances in Geo Nodes with noise texture over time

Tags: mesh, texturing, geometry-nodes

in the attached blend, there is a transition between a grid of instanced ico spheres and a grid of instanced cubes - modulated by a noise texture and controlled by a greater than / less than ratio that is, itself controlled by a keyframed changing value. The change boundary is binary, either one or the other. I'd like to 'soften' that change by adding a scaling down (size current to size 0) over 20 frames pre change (of the existing cubes) and then a scaling up (size 0 to size current) over 20 frames post change (of the 'new' ico spheres cubes). I cant work out how to combine the transition data with the noise texture information and then apply that result to the ico sphere and cube instances so that they match up with the transition. Any ideas? Thanks JK.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use map range and scale instances to do that:

[image]

result:

[image]

Explanation:

Ok, i assume that you did understand your blend file - so i only explain my change:

You had already the less than/greater than nodes, to instantiate a icosphere or a cube.
All i did was making a range from a discrete value.
I achieved this by using a map range node.
So i took your discrete value (the keyframed) and put this in one map range value. Then i added/subtracted a value (my new value node) to the from value so i could "stretch" the discrete value to a range in that the mapping from 1 to 0 (scaling of instances) can happen.

Comment: Wow that's amazing! I'm a total novice with GN - if you could talk me through a bit about what's happening here, I'd be grateful. 

Comment: i tried to explain it - but you cannot be a total novice with GN if you came that far! ;)

Comment: Thank you - your explanation was very helpful. Tutorials really are what got me to this point. If you have tuts on YT or something, let me know.

Comment: i would recommend watching Johnny Matthews + Erindale, they make really good geometry nodes tutorials with great explanations